# How to run python web-crawler effectively

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a python web-crawler that get info and put it in SQL. Now I also have php page, that read this info from the SQL, and represent it. The problem is: in order that the crawler program to work, my computer has to stay 24/7 working. I have simple home computer- so its a problem. Does there is a diffrent way to run the web-crawler? Or do I have to run it on my pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are monitoring pages that get updated constantly then yes you will need to run it on *some* computer that is on 24/7.  You can either use a cron job or a continuous loop (with some monitoring).  If you don't want to run it on your home machine, I would recommend getting a free AWS account.  You can get an EC2 micro instance which will allow you to run your python script and an S3 database instance which will allow you to store the information.

Here is a [link to AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/)